# Why can't I define an unnamed enum in the return type of a lambda function?

Tags: c++

This code:

```
void f() {
    auto determineType = []() -> enum {Type_ONE, Type_TWO} {
            return Type_ONE;
    };
}
```

fails to compile:

```
testcase-enum-in-lambda.cpp:3:36: error: unnamed enumeration must be a definition
```

Why isn't this allowed in C++? It is very clear what this does. The unnamed enum can be associated with the definition of the lambda and could have the same scope. I don't see any problems related to such a construct, except that it probably isn't specified in the C++ standard.

Why isn't this allowed in C++?

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of this question. Is there some set of rules that one could come up with and add to the standard to make this legitimate code? Probably. What would it matter if there was? It isn't legal now, and there are no proposals to make it legal. Indeed, a similar proposal for allowing unnamed structs as return types was shot down a few years back, and that was way more useful than this.

Comment: The reason is no one has taken the effort to propose it and get it approved by the committee. `enum class` was created to be a modern version of `enum`. Since it doesn't work without a name, this probably isn't a high priority for them.

Comment: @NicolBolas agree

Comment: Why not just do `auto determineType = [](bool v) { enum {Type_ONE, Type_TWO};` or `auto determineType = [](bool v) -> int { enum {Type_ONE, Type_TWO};` if you're using C++11 instead?

Comment: Why should this be legal? It's not even legal for regular functions: https://godbolt.org/z/Kee4ar

Answer (score 0):

Explicit return type in lambda expresses the type you are returning, it does not define a new type.

`[]() -> Type { }`

As far as I know, allowing a type definition here is a novel idea that isn't yet expressed in C++.

C++ supports type deduction (via decltype prior to c++14, automatically after).  Type deduction can appear to be defining a new type as in this example from [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype)

```
template<typename T, typename U>
auto add(T t, U u) -> decltype(t + u) // return type depends on template parameters
                                      // return type can be deduced since C++14
{
    return t + u;
}
```

but despite decltype(t + u) appearing to identify a previously undeclared type, even in this case the type is either T, U, or some other pre-defined type `V operator+(T, U)`

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with doing something like this?  It's no good declaring a return type that's only known by the lambda...

```
typedef enum 
{ 
    Type_ONE, 
    Type_TWO 
}
teTypes;


void f() 
{
    auto determineType = []() -> teTypes 
    {
        return teTypes::Type_ONE;
    };
}
```

---

FYI I recommend Ivan Cukic's book:
https://www.amazon.co.uk/Functional-Programming-C-Ivan-Cukic/dp/1617293814

It contains a good description about what the C++ compiler does for you in the background to make lambdas work (generating a class in the background etc).

Also see https://blog.feabhas.com/2014/03/demystifying-c-lambdas/